# How do I get the notification to take me to the desired viewController?

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

I'm working on a project but struggling to get the notification to take me to my "NotiViewController". Sometimes it works as desired but other times it just opens my app to whatever viewController I was last on.

I hacked this code together a few online sources:

```
extension QuestionViewController: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate{
   func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: 
   UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> 
   Void) {
      let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NotiViewControllerID") 
      as! NotiViewController
      show(vc, sender: Any?.self)        
      completionHandler()
}
```

I want to be able to send a notification that asks the user a question, then once it is clicked have the user taken to a answer...

eg notificationQuestion: "How many states are in the contiguous United States?" =>tap notification => loads the appropriate NotiViewController: "48"

Comment: `whatever viewController I was last on` sounds like there is a `NotiViewController` being displayed, which probably has no code to handle the notification (so nothing happens). Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. I added some code to handle the notification on that viewController and things started working but now if I quit the app. the notification loads the NotiViewcontroller, as it should, but the app doesn't hold on the Int variable that was used for the text that was used in the notification to begin with. Current issue example: 
*quits app.
notification pops up: How many wheels do bicycles have? => tap notification=> loads NotiViewController with: There are 48 states in the contiguous United States.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    //when application is close

    if let userInfo = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] as? [AnyHashable : Any] {
        print(userInfo)
        self.getBGUserInfo(userInfo: userInfo)
        // if notification call to redirect perticular page

    }
}
func getBGUserInfo(userInfo : [AnyHashable : Any] )  {
    //get userInfo details here
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "NotificationRedirect"), object: nil)
}
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "NotificationRedirect"), object: nil)
}
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "NotificationRedirect"), object: nil)
}

//In ViewController which open first while open app
//In ViewDidLoad
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.receiveTestNotification(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "NotificationRedirect"), object: nil)
//Over

func receiveTestNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
    let notName : String = String(describing: notification.name.rawValue)
    if (notName == "NotificationRedirect"){
        //Redirect your NotiViewController
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks trushali... I'm a rookie iOs programmer only 4 months in, so it's a little complex but I'm trying to make sense of it. I'm trying to simply save the a particular Int variable that persists after the app quits and loads that exact same Int variable.

Here I think I'm saving the variable in the notification scheduler func:
userDefaults.standard.set(intVar, forKey:"savedIntVar")

Here I'm trying to load IntVar in the NotiViewController after quit, but to no avail:
if let x = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "savedIntVar") as? Int {
                notiFreeze = x}

Comment: what actually happen is  it not saved intvar in userdefault?

Comment: It was strange, for some reason whenever i scheduled the notification from inside the viewDidLoad func, it was as if my  random number variable wasn't being saved. It works as it should when I schedule the notification in an action button though.
It's been tough getting the notifications under control. Do you know of a way to clear the notification from the notification center once the app opens?? 

If the user clicks a notification that stayed around for too long, tapping it would may not load the matching randomnumber for the IntVar. Clearing the notification would be a quick fix.

Comment: found this quick fix to clear out the notifications:         UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllDeliveredNotifications(). I'm all good now and my app is almost ready to ship. It's called Joke Spree. Thanks, everyone.